# PHP PDO Prepared Statement INSERT INTO SQLSTATE[21S01]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a simple create function using prepared statements, but PHP doesn't like me today.

```
function prepared_create ( $db, $table, $values, $columns = null ) {
    // Exit if database, table of values are undefined
    if  ( !isset ( $db, $table, $values )  )  { return 'Prepared Create: Insufficient parameters'; }

    if  ( isset ( $columns )  ) {
        $statement = $db->prepare("insert into $table  ( $columns )  values  ( :values )");
        $statement->execute( array ( ':values' => $values ) );
    } else {
        $statement = $db->prepare("insert into $table values ( :values )");
        $statement->execute( array ( ':values' => $values ) );
    }
}
```

Then I execute:

```
print_r  ( prepared_create ( $db, 'php_keyvalue', '"hello", "sir"' )  );
```

And am greeted with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /var/www/public/php-database-skeleton/connect-database.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/public/php-database-skeleton/connect-database.php(96): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/public/php-database-skeleton/index.php(20): prepared_create(Object(PDO), 'php_keyvalue', '"hello", "sir"') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/public/php-database-skeleton/connect-database.php on line 96
```

I've tried a bunch of things:

- Entering data for $value in array form
- Entering data for $value with quotes (single/double)
- Entering data for $value with backticks

Thing is, when I execute the same query manually:

```
insert into php_keyvalue values ( "Hello", "Sir" );
```

I get a:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Resulting in:

```
mysql> select * from php_keyvalue;
+-------------+---------+
| keyname     | value   |
+-------------+---------+
| first entry | correct |
| entered     | mentor  |
| entered     | mentor  |
| Hello       | Sir     |
+-------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The thread you mention does not describe my issue. I have 2 columns and 2 values, or am I overlooking something?